# CORS issues when trying to access NASA layers from ArcGIS JS API

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, arcgis-online, cors, nasa

I am trying to bring an ImageMapLayer into an ArcGIS JS API project.  The layer is here:

https://maps.disasters.nasa.gov/ags04/rest/services/ca_fires_202008/sentinel2/MapServer

I am creating the layer like this:

```js
export const SC2Sept29 = new MapImageLayer({
    url:
        'https://maps.disasters.nasa.gov/ags04/rest/services/ca_fires_202008/sentinel2/MapServer',
});
```

When adding it to the map, I get the classic cors error:

```js
Access to fetch at 'https://maps.disasters.nasa.gov/ags04/rest/services/ca_fires_202008/sentinel2/MapServer/547
?f=json' from origin 'https://8080-ea244033-ed39-4cd4-86f7-6fb2cfbea40b.ws-us02.gitpod.io' 
has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the 
requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 
'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

I was under the impression that NASA's GIS/ESRI data is available for public use.  Are their servers not configured for CORS?  What am I missing here?

Comment: Seth, there's a problem with you code snippet: The MapImageLayer URL should end with "/MapServer".  Not the ""/547" grouplayer.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up.  I was aware of that - I justed edited it out.  That doesn't seem to have any effect on the CORS issue though.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check into the webserver, if you are hosting a web application has CORS headers or not
2. The parameter `Allow Origin` in the portal end
   [Restrict cross-domain requests to your portal](https://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/portal/10.7/administer/windows/restrict-cross-domain-requests-to-your-portal.htm)
3. Check whether the webserver is been added as a Trusted Server in the application or not, Search for `trustedservers` in  [esri/config](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-config.html#request),
   and if it is not added, then the CORS issue might arise, giving the error:
   **No-Access-Control-Allow-Origin**

Comment: Thanks for this info...would you mind elaborating a bit?  I am not in control of the server/portal serving the layer, that is NASA's.  As far as my app, its a static web page app, pretty simple.  The CORS error I posted was from a webpack dev server spun up by gitpod, but I get the same error when using my local machine and localhost.  I am *not* getting CORS errors with other layers from ArcGIS server in the same app.  The app will end up hosted on github pages.  Can you elaborate on how I can use `esriConfig` to modify the requests to automatically enable CORS?